# Java Inheritance + Hibernate6 + JPA - How to prevent selecting all child tables when joining on parent?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, orm

I'm working on a Java application that uses Hibernate6 + JPA.

I have classes like

```
class Thing {
    
    Parent parent

}
```

```
class Parent {
   
}
```

```
class ChildA extends Parent {
    
}
```

```
class ChildB extends Parent {

}
```

I want to be able to write a query like `SELECT * FROM Thing JOIN Parent JOIN ChildA` but NOT select any data from ChildB.

I've tried making the parent table use TABLE_PER_CLASS and JOINED inheritance strategies, and write a HQL query like:

```
SELECT t FROM Thing t
JOIN t.parent p
WHERE
    TYPE(p) = ChildA
```

but this still selects all the child data from ChildA and ChildB, ie:  `SELECT * FROM Thing Join Parent Join ChildA Join ChildB`...

I could implement a Java Model that uses composition instead, but my situation highly favors inheritance, as it requires many less cascading changes in the code base.

Is there a model and combination of annotations to get Hibernate + JPA to produce the desired query?

I've tried the above model and HQL query, expecting to the ORM to return `Thing` with a `ChildA` using an efficient query.  I get the data I requested, but it creates an inefficient query that asks for more data than I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "TREAT" instead of type. The JPA (2.1) specification section 4.4.9 states:

```
If during query execution the first argument to the TREAT operator is not a subtype (proper or improper) of the target type, the path is considered to have no value, and does not participate in the determination of the result. That is, in the case of a join, the referenced object does not participate in the result, and in the case of a restriction, the associated predicate is false. Use of the TREAT operator therefore also has the effect of filtering on the specified type (and its subtypes) as well as performing the downcast.
```

You should be able to use:

```
"SELECT t from Thing t JOIN TREAT(t.parent AS ChildA) p"
```

to return only Things with ChildA parents.

Comment: The query performance though is provider specific, so if this doesn't work, I'd file a bug/enhancement request and try another provider. A workaround, ugly was it is, would be to make the relationship lazy and fetch the child you want directly: "select t, p from ChildA p join Thing t on t.parent = p". Ugly as that seems, your provider should fetch them both as you want, and when you go and try to touch the t.parent relationship, it should find the ChildA instance in the cache so not need to query for it (again though, provider specific).

Comment: Thanks so much for this feedback.  This was a key piece to executing the query how I wanted.  I had a few other things I ran across which I'll leave in a comment below.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Chris's answer helped a lot, there were a few other pieces I needed though.

I needed to set LazyLoading in my 'Thing' class, like so:

```
class Thing {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Parent parent;

}
```

I also had to select the child class, ie:

```
SELECT t, ca
FROM Thing t
JOIN TREAT (t.parent as ChildA) ca
```

otherwise I was not getting back all the data from ChildA.

And although it wasn't part of my original question, I had decendants hanging off of ChildA, like

```
class ChildA {
  List<GrandChild> grandChildren
}

class GrandChild {
  ChildA childA
}
```

In order to include all decedents in my query, I had to JOIN FETCH them.

```
SELECT t, ca
FROM Thing t
JOIN TREAT (t.parent as ChildA) ca
JOIN FETCH ca.grandChildren gc
```

Note this wouldn't work if I:

- did `JOIN TREAT FETCH (t.parent as ChildA) ca`, in that case it created a query that wouldn't execute.
- didn't include `ca` in the select statement